# Почему сервер не разбирает urlencoded form?

Tags: javascript, php

Отправляю запрос в формате `x-www-form-urlencoded` (заголовок явно указан), на сервере читаю `$_POST` и там абсолютно пусто... При этом данные доступны вот так: `file_get_contents("php://input")` (получаю закодированную строку). Почему так происходит? Почему сервер сам не разбирает запрос в `$_POST`?

P.S. Проблема проявилась когда попытался перелезть с `$.ajax` на `fetch`. До этого все работало!

Пример отправки запроса:

```
const fetchUrlEncoded = (url, data) => fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
    body: new URLSearchParams(data),
});

await fetchUrlEncoded('/ajax/myscript.php', {x: 123, y: 321});
```

P.P.S. Вообще не помню отправлял ли я когда-нибудь в этом формате POST запросы. PHP вообще должен их парсить? Может это нормально? О_о Что тогда мне через `parse_str` данные разбирать?

Пытался кстати еще через `multipart/form-data` отправить и тоже нефига не разбирает!!! Да что с этим fetch не так? Или это я такой криворукий? =(

```
const createFormData = data => Object.entries(data).reduce((f, [k, v]) => {
    f.append(k, v);
    return f;
}, new FormData());

const fetchFormData = (url, data) => fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8'},
    body: createFormData(data),
});
```

Comment: В обоих случаях Content-Type неправильный. Зачем вы его вообще указываете, если он прописывается браузером автоматически?

Comment: @andreymal как это он неправильный? Что вы имеете ввиду? Браузер не должен его прописывать, вроде, если указан в запросе

Comment: Вот именно поэтому и не работает. Уберите `headers` отсюда, и браузер автоматически пропишет правильный Content-Type и всё заработает. Посмотрите, какой Content-Type прописывает браузер, и сравните со своим — вы увидите, почему ваш неправильный.

Comment: @andreymal че то я не догоняю... Как браузер может определить какой тип запроса я хочу послать? Для него все данные - текст. Зачем же тогда существует возможность задавать заголовки если я не могу указать тип данных?

Comment: У вас в `body` вовсе не текст, а объекты специальных типов. По типу объекта `body` и определяет. Отличить `FormData` от `URLSearchParams` не составляет никакого труда (instanceof и всё такое)

Comment: @andreymal а если посылать json?

Comment: Вот тогда уже действительно придётся писать `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`

Comment: @andreymal и потом - чем плохи мои заголовки? Я сравнил - браузер один в один устанавливает тот же самый Content-Type что у меня был (пока я его не удалил)

Comment: Не один в один, сравните ещё раз повнимательнее. Ну или покажите скриншоты, где видно один в один, потому что я уже запускал ваш код и у меня было не один-в-один

Comment: @andreymal а, теперь увидел. Я написал просто `x-www-form-urlencoded`, вместо `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. А вот с form-data хз, там разница только в том что браузер еще `boundary` к нему дописал. Честно говоря я даже не знаю что это такое =) Какой-то хэш моих параметров?

Comment: Почитайте в интернете про multipart/form-data формат. Boundary это строка, используемая для разделения разных полей формы друг от друга, генерируется автоматически случайным образом отдельно для каждого запроса. Поэтому прописать свой Content-Type для multipart/form-data вы при всём желании не сможете, так как не угадаете, какой boundary выберет браузер (хотя можно вместо объекта FormData использовать просто текст и в него запихнуть какой угодно boundary самостоятельно, но зачем?)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, прояснили